A android shell script for converting Bluetooth gamepad input to mouse click
Is there any gamepad mapping app which converts gamepad input to mouse click events, not touch events! If not, can someone help me writing a script in shell which I can execute through adb, so that I can send mouse input event at specific coordinates according to the key pressed. I couldn't figure out how to write such a script.
I tried using get event and send event but I couldn't figure it out.
